# d3 mouseout changes attributes of selected element

Tags: jquery, attributes, d3.js, click, mouseout

I have SVG circles and text elements which change color when hovered over...

```
var texts = svgcontainer.selectAll('text.year')
.data(yeardata).enter().append("svg:a")
.attr('class', 'year')
.append('text').text(function(d) { return d;})
.attr('dx', function(d) { return Math.random()*containerWidth})
.attr('dy', function(d) { return Math.random()*containerWidth})
.attr("xlink:href", '#')
.attr('pointer-events', 'all')
.attr('font-size', function(d) { return scale2(d) })
.style('font-family', 'Arial')
.attr('font-weight', 'bold')
.attr('font-style', 'italic')
.attr('fill', '#161738')
.on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
  d3.select(this)
  .transition()
  .duration(200)
  .attr('font-size', function(d) { return 45 })
  .attr('opacity', .5);
  d3.select(circles[0][i])
  .style('fill', 'red');
})
.on("mouseout", function(d, i) {
  d3.select(this)
  .transition()
  .duration(200)
  .attr('font-size', function(d) { return scale2(d) })
  .attr('opacity', 1);
  d3.select(circles[0][i])
  .style('fill', '#3CCAFA');
})
.transition()
.duration(1100)
.attr('dx', function(d) { return d*space + 15.5 })
.attr('dy', 34);
```

I also want the selected (clicked on element) to have the same attributes of a one that is hovered over.

```
$('.year').click(function() {
val = ... // this works
years = d3.selectAll('.year');
d3.select(this)
  .attr('opacity', .5)
d3.select(circles[0][val])
  .style('fill', 'red');
})
```

My problem is that the mouseover event overrides the attributes set in the click event.  I tried to add an id to the clicked on element and set its attributes in the css file but this didn't work.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you tried using D3 for both `click` and `mouseover` event handlers?

Comment: Do you mean adding a .on("click", function() { //change attributes }) to the same method?  Yeah, I tried that but maybe it was conflicting with the other click event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're trying to do but I think you're probably on the right track setting an `id` or `class` on the clicked element.  But instead of using CSS you could try changing your `mouseover` implementation to use an id or class selector instead of the node selector you're using now.

So:

```
d3.select("#clickedId");
```

or:

```
d3.select(".clickedClass");
```

Then you can set the styles on your moused over circle based on the styles found on the clicked circle.

Comment: Hey Scott, thanks for the reply.  I'll play around with your suggestion but just to clarify what the problem is... Simple version: I have 2 numbers.  I hover over them and they change styling just fine, I mouseout and the styling goes away, all is swell. However, I want one of these numbers to be the selected number.  (You select something by clicking on it.) The selected number should always have the styling of a number that is hovered over. When I click a number it changes styling like it should, but because of the mouseout function, styling for the selected number goes away on mouseout.

Comment: Can you just mark the clicked number with a class that indicates "clicked" and then check for it in your mouseout before you change the styles back?  The clicked class would indicate the styles should not be touched.

Comment: That sounds simple enough.  I tried this:  if (!$(this).is('#clicked')) {
        console.log("doesnt have clicked id"); // do stuff here } and added the 'clicked' id to the element that was clicked but it's still not working =/